# Discuss cases for Picard's Theorem based on initial condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following definition of Picard's Theorem:

Let $f$ be a real-valued bounded continuous function on an open subset $D$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$, let
$$
M=\sup \{|f(x, y)|:(x, y) \in D\},
$$
and let $(a, b)$ be a point in $D$ such that the rectangle
$$
R=\{(x, y):|x-a| \leqslant h,|y-b| \leqslant k\}
$$
is contained in $D$ and $M h \leqslant k$. If, in addition, the function $f$ satisfies the Lipschitz condition that there exists a positive real number $A$ such that, for all elements $\left(x, y_1\right)$ and $\left(x, y_2\right)$ in $D$,
$$
\left|f\left(x, y_1\right)-f\left(x, y_2\right)\right| \leqslant A\left|y_1-y_2\right|,
$$
Then, the differential equation
$$
u^{\prime}(x)=f(x, u(x))
$$
has a unique solution in the interval $[a-h, a+h]$ such that
$$
u(a)=b .
$$
**Discuss the cases in which
$$
f(x, y)= \begin{cases}y^{\frac{1}{4}}, & y \geqslant 0 \\ 0, & y<0\end{cases}
$$
and: (i) $(a, b)=(0,0)$
(ii) $(a, b)=(0,1)$;
(iii) $(a, b)=(1,0)$.**

I've shown that (i) does not satisfy the Picard conditions because it doesn't satisfy the Lipschitz condition (Proof by contradiction)
(ii) does satisfy the Picard conditions, since $f_y$ is bounded so Lipschitz is satisfied, and clearly continuous, bounded with $Mh \leqslant k$. I think that we must enforce that $k<1$, as this fails at 0, **is this correct**?
Also for part (iii), I'm confused as to why this is a separate case to part (i). Since $f(x,y)$ is only dependant on $y$, surely the result for (i) also applies?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks! For (ii), my thinking is that the y values have to stay away from zero, because if it hits zero, then the Lipschitz condition fails. e.g. if $k=2$ then zero will be in R?

Comment: I agree with you about everything.